# SoapUI requests and responses to text file using groovy

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui

How can I save my REST project in SoapUI Open Source all requests and responses that was ran to a text file divided in sections test by test.
I would like to use a Groovy code to do it, Please may someone help me?

Example:

> Test 1 - Title
> Request code
> Response code
> *
> *Test 1 - Title
> Request code
> Response code
> *

I tried to save the [Dump File](https://www.soapui.org/getting-started/working-with-soapui/saving-responses/) but I need all request and response information with titles and all test steps together in the same file.

How can I solve my problem using REST API and save all requests and responses  that was ran?

Comment: Have you tried using [TestRunner Command-Line Arguments](https://www.soapui.org/docs/test-automation/running-from-command-line/functional-tests/), specifically the `-A` or `-a` options? You can accomplish the same from the [TestRunner from SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/docs/test-automation/running-from-soapui/functional-tests/), if you select "Export All" under "Reports".

Comment: Dear Tompsett,

I like the way that TestRunner biuld the reports, helps a lot. I'm looking a way to improve it using Groovy script. 

Thank you too much.
Best Regards!